vue input components not rendering correctly after merging projects
I am attempting to merge an existing vue/ vuetify project into Ionic. Mostly working well, but I cannot get any form inputs to render correctly - they all appear vertically:
<template>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSizes"   @change="emit('changeImages')" />
  <label for="checkboxSizes">Random sizes</label>
  ....
  ....
</template>

appears as

in the Ionic project, and not as

like it should.
The same occurs for other html inputs, and also for Vuetify input components. Other Vuetify components (e.g. v-chip) appear correctly.

Look like a CSS problem: the width is smaller than it should be. Can you inspect it?

Most of the body styles (including width) in the inspector are struck through, meaning that they are overridden - pesumably by ionic (they aren't struck through in my orginal non-ionic project)

You can still override it: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables

Well, yes, overriding the element's width does work. But this is a very messy solution - I would need to override separately for several types of input elements, each having a  different width. To my mind, one of the whole points of using Vue (and similar frameworks) is to avoid messing about with CSS (or even learning it in the first place :) ).

This is a very wrong assumption. Vue helps you move forward by abstracting the principle of state but you need to master HTML/CSS and especially JS. Vue is not meant to avoid you to learn proper foundations. Each platform you are shipping your code to (mobile, browsers, desktop etc...) has an innate platform styling. On the Web we have CSS resets for a reason. Looks like Ionic also brings some defaults you are not very satisfied with. You will need to overwrite them to your liking unfortunately. This is btw not even a VueJS problem but more of Ionic's way of doing things.

Turned out to be nothing to do with Ionic. In merging two projects together, the  section of one component was not scoped, so was affecting components it shouldn't.
    <style scoped>  /* <--- I forgot this 'scoped' */

      label {
       display: inline-block;
       margin-left: 10px;
       width: 20px;
      }
      line {
        stroke: darkGreen;
        stroke-width: 5px;
      }
    </style>

